# Action in grails form is not working

Tags: grails

I am trying to make a simple creation of account and when create button is clicked it should perform the action "create" but I get an error saying that 
**HTTP Status 404 - "/WEB-INF/grails-app/views/users/create.gsp" not found.**

Here is my code block for the index.gsp

```
<!-- CREATEFORM -->
<div id="id02" class="modal">
  <g:form class="modal-content animate" controller="users" action="create">
    <div class="imgcontainer">
      <span onclick="document.getElementById('id02').style.display='none'" class="close" title="Close Modal">&times;</span>
        <div class="container" style="text-align:center">
            <b><h style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 30px">CREATE AN ACCOUNT</h></b><br/>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" name="uname" required/>

      <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="psw" required/>

      <input type="text" placeholder="First Name" name="firstName" required/>

      <input type="text" placeholder="Last Name" name="lastName" required/>

      <input type="text" placeholder="Age" name="age" required/>
      <br/>
      <input type="date" placeholder="Birth Date" name="birthdate" required/>
      <br/>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Student Number" name="studno" required/><br/>

      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="remember"> Remember me</input>
      </label>
      <br/>
      <button type="submit" style="width: 100px; margin-right:10px;" >Create</input>
      <button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('id02').style.display='none'" class="cancelbtn">Cancel</button>

    </div>
    </div>
  </g:form>
</div>
```

and Here is my code block for the usersController.

```
class usersController {    
    def index(){}
    def create()
    {
        new Users(userid:params.uname,password:params.psw).save()
        new UserInfo(studentno:params.studno,age:params.age,birth_date:params.birthdate,first_name:params.firstName,last_name:params.lastName,user_id:params.uname).save()
    }
}
```

And here's the error

[image: Error Page]

Comment: Add `<g:actionSubmit value="Create"/>` instead of ` <button type="submit" style="width: 100px; margin-right:10px;" >Create</input>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Grails for action (non gsp) you need to **render** something to the client,
otherwise it executes everything inside that action, but returns 404 gsp not found response, if there is no render / redirection statement  it consider that action as a gsp but it is not gsp actually, therefore it responds 404.

You could render something data like list / JSON or simple string as follows.

```
def create() {
 //your business logic is here
 render "operation performed successfully"

}
```

Answer (score 2):

> HTTP Status 404 - "/WEB-INF/grails-app/views/users/create.gsp" not found.

Because you are saving data using create action but after saving data there is no redirect option or `create.gsp` available. So grails will look first is there any redirect option available and try to redirect `create.gsp`

Check bellow code changes which will save `user id` to `userInfo` table and redirect to index page

So change your `usersController`

```
class usersController {
    def index() {}

    def create() {
        def user = new Users(userid: params.uname, password: params.psw).save()
        def userInfo = new UserInfo(studentno: params.studno, age: params.age, birth_date: params.birthdate, first_name: params.firstName, last_name: params.lastName, user_id: user.id).save()
        if (user && userInfo) {
            flash.message = "User created successfully"
            redirect action: 'index'
        } else {
            flash.message = "Problem in user creation"
            redirect action: 'index'
        }

    }
}
```

And add bellow code to your `index.gsp`

```
${flash.message}
```

There are many ways to redirect to pages. You can use render, redirect, chain, forward ..etc

Please check grails [documentation](https://docs.grails.org/latest/ref/Controllers/redirect.html) for more information

Answer (score 0):

First of all what grails version do you use? If the latest one (3.3.4) so this [link](https://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#modelsAndViews) might be helpful.

Speaking shortly: if you don't specify what to render explicitly - grails tries to find the view to display the result of action execution as:

```
grails-app/views/<controllerName>/<actionName>.gsp
```

Looks like you don't have one.

**UPD**

There are several ways to render action's output in grails controller.
Define explicit content as:

```
def myAction() {
    ...
    render "Hello World!"
}
```

That will result in "white screen" with "Hello world!" text in top-left corner.

Another option is to create a gsp view in the conventional location as grails-app/views//.gsp - it will automatically be rendered after action execution if no specifying the *render* method invocation (like in the sample you've given)

The third option is to specify the model map:

```
def myAction() {
    ...
    [param1key: param1value, param2key: param2value, ...]
}
```

The model will be taken into account when rendering your gsp view.

Please read the documentation I gave link to. It's incredibly helpful.

Comment: I'm using 2.4.4 and can I ask how do I specify what to render?

Comment: @MagatLaw, updated the answer. The info above is relevant for grails 2.4.4 as well.